# awk - merge lines on the basis of multiple field matching

Tags: awk

I am new to shell commands and am trying to take the following:

```
05 ; 47.89 ; 971  
05 ; 49.23 ; 971
05 ; 1.44 ; 971
10 ; 61.42 ; 508
10 ; 37.40 ; 508
10 ; 0.39 ; 508
15 ; 45.09 ; 173
15 ; 52.60 ; 173
15 ; 0.00 ; 173
```

And output:

```
05 ; 971 ; 47.89 ; 49.23 ; 1.44
10 ; 508 ; 61.42 ; 37.40 ; 0.39
15 ; 173 ; 45.09 ; 52.60 ; 0.00
```

So far I tried:

```
awk -F';' '{ x[$1]=x[$1] " " $2; y[$2]=y[$2] " " $1; } END { for (k in x) print k,x[k];}' graphtemp.txt
```

which I know doesn't print column 3 as needed. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Do the input-lines always come in sets of three? That is -- do the output-lines always have five fields?

Answer (score 2):

Try this awk command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {c=$1 FS $3; if (c in a) a[c]=a[c] FS $2; else a[c]=$2}
     END{for (k in a) print k, a[k]}' file
```

**EDIT: Looks like you've `\r\n` at end of each line, try this modified code instead:**

```
awk -F '[ ;\r]+' 'BEGIN{OFS=";"} {c=$1 OFS $3;
  if (c in a) a[c]=a[c] OFS $2; else a[c]=$2} END{for (k in a) print k, a[k]}'
```

Comment: This solution also leaves out columns 1 and 3 from the results:

Comment: Did you test it? `c=$1 FS $3;` is combining both `$1 and $3` and that is the key of the associative array.

Comment: Hmm..I see it's working perfectly for you. For me it is only printing the values from column 2. I copied and pasted your code directly so I have no idea why it isn't working for me? cat graphtemp2.txt |awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {c=$1 FS $3; if (c in a) a[c]=a[c] FS $2; else a[c]=$2} END{for (k in a) print k, a[k]}'

Comment: BTW, in my example I only showed three lines for each match, in my data there are actually 11 lines for each match. Sorry if this is vital info, I was just trying to keep it simple.

Comment: No # of lines doesn't matter since my awk is going to process whole file. What is your awk version? And can you show me output of `head -1 graphtemp2.txt | od -c`

Comment: 0000000    0   1   -   0   0   0   5       ;       4   7   .   8   9
0000020    ;       9   7   1  \r  \n
0000027

Comment: I am also embarrassed to say I don't know what version of awk I have or even how to check. I am using iTerm on a Mac.

Comment: ~ 0000000    0   1   -   0   0   0   5       ;       4   7   .   8   9
~ 0000020    ;       9   7   1  \r  \n
~ 0000027

Comment: Ok I think this `\r\n` is causing problem.

Comment: The tilde is supposed to give me a line break?

Comment: let me see if I can recreate the problem with `\r\n` in the end.

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it worked out. If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F' *; *' '{a[$1 ";" $3]=a[$1 ";" $3] ";" $2} END {for (k in a) {print k a[k]}}' INPUTFILE
```

This might work for you/give you a starting point, if you really has the exact input file format.

See here in action: http://ideone.com/r44wjm

*Note:* this will give you an unsorted output (you can sort an array with (g)awk, but I'm leaving that to you.

How it works:

1. creates an array element for every `$1 ";" $3` (key), and appends the 2nd column to its value.
2. END loops over the keys of the array, print the key, and value.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For some reason that is not returning columns 1 or 3 in the results. It is just printing column 2. Any thoughts?

Comment: By the way, the value in column 3 will always be the same for matched values in column 1. And it doesn't need to be moved to column 2 in the output, it can remain in the last column if that's easier.

Answer (score 0):

(I overlooked the requirement to use semicolons as the output field separator. Because I'm using concatenated keys below, I found it easier to manage semicolons inline rather than declaring OFS in a BEGIN block.)

Build a concatenated key for an array. Concatenate the second column to the existing values in the array. Print each key and value to stdout.

```
$ cat test.awk
{
   x = sprintf("%s ; %s", $1, $3)
   if (x in a ) 
      a[x] = sprintf("%s ; %s", a[x], $2) 
  else
      a[x] = "; " $2
}
END {
    for (k in a) print k, a[k]
}
```

Sort for convenience. It doesn't matter how many rows have the same values for the first and third columns in the input file.

```
$ awk -F";" -f test.awk test.dat | sort
05  ;  971 ;  47.89  ;  49.23  ;  1.44 
10  ;  508 ;  61.42  ;  37.40  ;  0.39 
15  ;  173 ;  45.09  ;  52.60  ;  0.00
```

Comment: I can't get that to work, but maybe I'm misunderstanding how to implement it properly? For example, where do I insert -F';'? Or this unnecessary for some reason? Sorry for the basic questions, I am very new to this.

Comment: The `-F` flag determines the input field separator. Both `cat test.awk` and `awk -F";" -f test.awk test.dat | sort` are command lines; my command prompt is "$". If you use the same kind of awk I use (gawk), just type that on the command line and you should get the same output. (I think the program *should* work for most versions of awk. There are quite a few different versions of awk, and I don't bother to try to keep the differences straight in my head. I just look them up when I'm surprised.)

Comment: After this most recent edit this answer has become 90% identical to my answer.