# How to remove duplicate columns and merge their unique value

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, scripting

I'd like to convert my source file which has the following values:

```
col1|col2|col3
1|a|desc1
1|a|desc2
1|b|desc3
1|b|desc4
1|b|desc5
2|c|desc6
2|c|desc7
```

into:

```
col1|col2|col3
1|a|desc1 desc2
1|b|desc3 desc4 desc5
2|c|desc6 desc7
```

It's basically a column 1 and column 2 duplicate removal but their column 3 will be merged. Looking into awk or perl or sed or bash code - whichever has the minimal processing power consumption is preferred.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but you can start with [awk merge line on the basis of multiple field matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952887/awk-merge-lines-on-the-basis-of-multiple-field-matching)

Comment: Thanks, fredtantini for editing. My bad.

Comment: Can you please share the code you created to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|" }
{
    curr = $1 FS $2
    if (curr == prev) {
        rec = rec " " $3
    }
    else {
        if (rec) print rec
        rec = $0
    }
    prev = curr
}
END { if (rec) print rec }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
col1|col2|col3
1|a|desc1 desc2
1|b|desc3 desc4 desc5
2|c|desc6 desc7
```

Comment: and most importantly (since just about any solution will "work") I expect you can read it without the Rosetta Stone and a Batman decoder ring :-). You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

here is an awk-oneliner, do the merge and keep the order:

```
awk -F'|' '{k=$1FS$2;if(a[k])a[k]=a[k] OFS $3;else{a[k]=$0;b[++i]=k}}
           END{for(x=1;x<=i;x++)print a[b[x]]}' file
```

Comment: Thanks, Kent! Awesome one liner! Nailed it.

Comment: Shortened  `awk -F\| 'c=a[k=$1FS$2]{a[k]=a[k]" "$3}!c{a[k]=$0;b[++i]=k}END{while(++x<=i)print a[b[x]]}' file`. It has cut the space out between the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a perl solution:

```
open $fh, "<", "yourfile.txt";
%h = ();
$head = <$fh>;

while (<$fh>) {
    if ($_ =~ /(\d\|[a-z]\|)(.*)/) {
        $h{$1} .= "$2 ";
    }
}

print $head;
foreach (sort keys %h) {
    print "$_$h{$_}\n";
}
```

You can use a regex to get the combined `col1` and `col2` and store it as a hash key, then append the `col3` values to that key whilst looping over the rest of the file.

Comment: Thanks, arco444! Substituted with the correct source file and it works too.

Answer (score 1):

Perl from command line,

```
perl -lne'
  /(.+\|)(.+)/ or next;
  $h{$1} or push @r, $1;
  push @{ $h{$1} }, $2;

  END { print $_, "@{$h{$_}}" for @r }
' file
```